# What graphic card can I use for Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: graphics

I use a tower for my Ubuntu 20.4. Today when I boot my PC I get the bios but beyond that I get no GUI only the message on the monitor that the video feed is missing or alternatively the message

```
Input Signal out of range 
Current settings H=94kHz V= 50 Hz 
Change Settings to 1920 x 1200 - 60 Hz
```

After trying out VGA Port with the old cable, digital port also with an old cable and then VGA Port with a brand new cable and always getting the same result apart for a few colourful lines in between I deduced that my graphic card might be broken, which is possible since it isn't a new PC.

So here comes the question. Finally....

**If I buy a new graphic card, which one will work with Ubuntu 20.4? Is there a way to find out before I buy one?**

I use kde, which shouldn't make any difference I guess. But it should be able to support 2 monitors.

Comment: Since there is no Ubuntu version 20.4 I would have to say none. If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 almost any card usually can be made to work. Before buying a new card boot from the try option and see if there is a problem with the card that way.

Comment: "boot from the try option" what exactly do you mean with that? Trying to get in the BIOS? 
Or trying to boot from the installation DVD? If the platter: I did that with the same result.

Comment: Put in the live media and set the computer via bios to boot from that media. You get a try and an install option. Use the try option . If the same errors occur with the try option then maybe the monitor and or the video card has gone bad.

Comment: That is what I did. Of course I should first try to connect the monitor with a different PC and see if it works with it. But since it shows me the error message in a nice resolution I guess the graphic card is the culprit.

Comment: monitor runs perfectly with another PC, so buying a new graphic card it is.....

Comment: Not necessarily. First try the option with safe graphics or use `nomodeset`.